# Multimap and gson performance

Tags: java, performance, gson, guava, multimap

I am using both Gson and Guava. I have a class that I want to serialize that looks like something like this [sscce](http://sscce.org)

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
public class FooManager {
  private Multimap<String, Foo> managedFoos;
  // other stuff
}
```

Gson doesn't know how to serialize that. So I did this:

```
public final class FoomapSerializer implements
                          JsonSerializer<Multimap<String, Foo>> {
  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  private static final Type t =
          new TypeToken<Map<String, Collection<Foo>>>() {}.getType();

  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Multimap<String, Foo> arg0, Type arg1,
        JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
    return arg2.serialize(arg0.asMap(), t);
  }
}
```

However, I'm afraid calling `.asMap()` over and over again will be slow, even if the underlying `Map` rarely changes. (The serializations of the `Foo` objects will change often, but the mapping itself does not after initialization). Is there a better way?

Comment: You say that you are afraid it will; but have you timed it against alternative approaches, for instance using [caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/)? Also, have you tried Jackson?

Comment: I have not timed it against alternative approaches but I did time it against itself; in other words, I compared calling `asMap` repeatedly on the same map to `asMap` on different duplicate maps with the same data and the same map was not much faster. My caliper test may have been bad though.

Comment: Also, eveything I've read suggests that Jackson used to be faster 2-3 years ago but that Gson is faster now.

Comment: 2-3 years ago was an eternity ago ;) I wouldn't discard Jackson that easily... In my use case it is faster than Gson, for instance.

Comment: Does Jackson support serialization of Guava collections natively?

Comment: Multimap.asMap returns a cached view of the Multimap in O(1) time.  It is not an expensive operation.

Comment: Louis, that's great! So if you were in my use-case situation (barring no other information) you think my solution is appropriate? If so, make that comment into an answer and I'll checkmark it.

Comment: Natively no, but there is a module for that

Comment: As Louis said, using `asMap()` is fine. My recommendation would be to make your `FoomapSerializer` into a generic `Multimap` serializer. It could implement `JsonSerializer<Multimap<?, ?>>` and return `context.serialize(src.asMap(), typeOfSrc)`. You don't need the `Type t` field to do the serialization... the `Type` for the multimap is passed to you in the method.

Comment: @ColinD You do need it, because the newly serialized type is not a `Multimap`

Comment: @durron597: ...good point! Hmm. That does make things difficult. If Gson's `TypeToken` had all the features of Guava's [TypeToken](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), specifically the `resolveType` method which could be used to resolve the return `Type` of the `asMap()` method. As it is though, maybe not.

Comment: Er, that should probably say "It would be easy if".

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, since Gson just deals with `Type`, you could just use the Guava `TypeToken`.

Comment: @ColinD I would definitely upvote an answer with a code sample that does what you describe, I haven't had occasion to use Guava's TypeToken yet.

Comment: Also I would definitely need to implement some sort of TypeToken LRC cache, which doesn't seem all that straightforward to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multimap.asMap returns a cached view of the Multimap in O(1) time. It is not an expensive operation.  (In point of fact, it's quite cheap, requiring at most one allocation.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a generic serializer for multimaps using Guava's `TypeToken`. There are some variations on this you could do if you wanted, like creating instances of the serializer for each multimap type you need to serialize so you only have to resolve the return type of `asMap()` once for each.

```
public enum MultimapSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Multimap<?, ?>> {
  INSTANCE;

  private static final Type asMapReturnType = getAsMapMethod()
      .getGenericReturnType();

  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Multimap<?, ?> multimap, Type multimapType,
      JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return context.serialize(multimap.asMap(), asMapType(multimapType));
  }

  private static Type asMapType(Type multimapType) {
    return TypeToken.of(multimapType).resolveType(asMapReturnType).getType();
  }

  private static Method getAsMapMethod() {
    try {
      return Multimap.class.getDeclaredMethod("asMap");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fascinating, I've never seen an `enum` used in this way. Is that simply a shorthand for singleton? If I'm using Guice's `@Singleton` it's not necessary to do it this way, right?

Comment: @durron597: Yeah, this is the `enum` singleton pattern, recommended by Josh Bloch in _Effective Java_ for things like this. While hardwired singletons are often a bad idea and using Guice to scope an object as a singleton is generally a better idea, this is not the type of object I'd consider injecting with Guice. It's a lightweight, stateless functional object and I'd just use it directly when registering type adapters with Gson.